# Cocos 2d and Game Center (Leaderboard issue)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I cant really find my answer after browsing (not a lot of topics on cocos2d with game center)

I currently have my sandbox game center set up and I am able to authenticate, but when I create the leaderboard it is launched sideways in portrait I assume. Tried rotating the view but nothing. My game runs only in landscape mode. I am running beta 3 0.99.5.  Here is my code for reference.

```
tempVC = [[RootViewController alloc] init];

GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

if (leaderboardController != nil)
{
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:tempVC.view];
    [tempVC presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
}
```

Really would appreciate any help.  Getting no response from the cocos2d board.

EDIT:

Fixed by changing auto-rotation to CCDirector.  Furthermore, I had issues with losing multi-touch functionality after showing gamecenter.  The dismissal for the board should use this:

```
[tempVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[tempVC.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Thanks... I could not get my leaderboard or acheivements to dismiss and your EDIT above solved it for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by changing auto-rotation to CCDirector.  Furthermore, I had issues with losing multi-touch functionality after showing gamecenter.  The dismissal for the board should use this:

```
[tempVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[tempVC.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Provided my comment as an answer...see below.

Comment: "Fixed by changing auto-rotation to CCDirector" what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

=I had this problem and was tearing my hair out for days, but I eventually got it to work perfectly in landscape mode, no matter what way the user is holding the phone. It's a bit weird, and if anyone knows better please let me know!

1 - I have to have the view (of the controller which calls the leaderboard) in portrait, in my case done in IB

2 - It only works if you support the portrait orientation (even if it looks like landscape) -

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

3 - You then need to resize & rotate the leaderboard -

```
[self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];

leaderboardController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0.0f));
leaderboardController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
leaderboardController.view.center = CGPointMake(240, 160);
```

4 - Hey presto! It's working fine. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

if it might help, I have found that simply removing the GKLeaderboard from the superview is not really enough, so after you use

[tempVC.view.superview removeFromSuperview];

you should also use

[tempVC release];

Without this the GKLeaderboardViewController is doing some weird things, like after the second call it is not auto rotating itself in the view.

I hope it help

Answer (score 1):

Using this on cocos2d v1.0.1, latest stable version as of Apr 19th, 2012, this actually doesn't allow the vc to disappear animated. Probably running this instead:

```
[tempVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[[[tempVC view] superview] performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.2];
[tempVC performSelector:@selector(release) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.3];
```

Comment: Good answer, but as of a recent iOS update (iOS 4?) you can now use blocks in this method to be a little less hacky: `[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL) completion:^(void)completion];` Ex: `[tempVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ [tempVC.view removeFromSuperview]; [tempVC release]; }];`

Answer (score 1):

The correct was is to implement and include this category:

.h

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@interface GKLeaderboardViewController (additions)
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "GKLeaderboardViewController+additions.h"

@implementation GKLeaderboardViewController (additions)
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
@end
```

Comment: You might want to make the same category on `GKGameCenterViewController`, `GKAchievementViewController` and the match making controller.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with GC launching in portrait on iPad when my Cocos2D game was in landscape.  Fixed this by deriving my GameKit controller from rootViewController instead of UIViewController.

@interface GCController :RootViewController  {

Comment: Nope didnt work for me. Same issue.  It appears the actual gameCenter view is landscape turned sideways.  So I have the game in landscape with a leaderboard that shows up covering less than half the screen and extends beyond the screen.  (Not sure if that makes any sense?) I am at a complete loss.

Answer (score 0):

Once i was having the same problem, I followed the Connor Denman's blog which works for me Here is the link
 http://connordenman.com/post/15554858770/presenting-a-modal-view-controller-in-cocos2d-iphone

Answer (score -1):

A GKLeaderboardViewController is used to display the default leaderboard, which is a portrait only view. To display a landscape leaderboard, you have to implement your own custom leaderboard view.

Edit: Since the initial writing of this, GKLeaderboardViewController has been improved to work just fine in any orientation.

Comment: So the one in games like Angry Birds is completely custom?  Im not sure I quite understand.

Comment: Angry Birds uses the Crystal SDK for its leaderboard.  http://www.crystalsdk.com/

Comment: Hmmm it appears this isn't entirely correct, unless you are talking about something else.  After some fiddling around with the Cocos2d default rotations, I got the leaderboard to properly display in landscape mode.  However my UIScrollView on the next scene was improperly displaying.  No clue what is going on.

Comment: How'd you manage to get the leaderboard to display in landscape mode?

Comment: It has something to do with Cocos2d auto-rotation.  If I use the CCDirector autorotation, it launches the leaderboard in landscape.  However, once dismissed I have other issues, like multi-touch not working anymore.  If I use the default UIView rotation, the leaderboard is launched in portrait but turned sideways.  No rotation efforts I make change it.